# Sequelize: I want to return all registries associated with a model if one of these registries has a specific key

Tags: javascript, database, sequelize.js

I have the tables **posts** and **tags** with a many-to-many relationship, and a junction table post_tags. I want to return all tags from a post if this post have one specific tag name.

The idea is to filter all posts by a specific tag.

I was doing like that:

```
const posts = await Post.findAll({
  include: {
    model: Tag,
    where: {
      name: 'specificTag',
    },
  },
});
```

This way I can filter posts with a specific tag, but it's not return all others tags related to that post.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
const posts = await Post.findAll({
  include: {
    model: Tag,
    where: {
      name: ['specificTag'], //  Same as using `name: { [Op.in]: ['specificTag'] }`
    },
  },
});
```

I'm not sure, though.

Comment: Okay. There is a two-step solution to your problem. 1) Return all the postIDs for a specificTagID. 2) Then using those postIDs, return all the tags related to the postIDs. This is one solution I come up with.

Answer (score 0):

So, It got like this:

```
const posts = await Post.findAll({
  include: {
    model: Tag,
    where: {
      name: 'specificTag',
    },
  },
});

const postsPromises = posts.map((post) => (
    Post.findOne({
      where: {
        id: post.id,
      },
      include: {
        model: Tag,
      },
    })
  ));

  const postsWithTags = await Promise.all(postsPromises);
```